# build complex filters UI for tables

Tags: reactjs, antd

why did Ant choose to implement the filters in this way - https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-head

the filters are hidden away and it is not easy to see. In case we want to build complex filter choices, it is not user-friendly.

Why did they not use components like https://ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-multiple or https://ant.design/components/cascader/ to implement filters as a component on the side ?

Answer (score 0):

That is just a simple filter to ease the life of developer when you want a quick filter. building everything into the table would make the table potentially much larger in bundle size.

however you can always implement your own filter with components that you mentioned and filter the data yourself and pass to the table.